# Ternary operator function for JavaScript 'get middle letter' Code War challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ternary

Code challenge: write a function that gets the middle letter(s) of a string of even or odd numbered letters, as a ternary operator.

My function is working for odd numbers. But it does not work for even numbers - it seems to be skipping letters.

eg.

```
getMiddle("testing") // the output is "t", this is correct.  
getMiddle("test") // the output is "et", it should be "es".
```

my code:

```
    function getMiddle(str) {
     return str.length % 2 === 0 ? str[str.length/2 - 1] + str[str.length/2 + 1] : str[Math.floor(str.length/2)];
    }
```

Comment: When it's even, you get the letters at positions one before and one after half the length; you skip the letter at exactly half the length.

Comment: The answer is very easy, I think you could see it if you try more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the length is is even, you want the 2 characters which are at the middle. You do that by taking the length of the string and divide it by 2.

That index in a zero based array will be the `s`.If you subtract 1 from the index, it will be the `e`. When you add +1, you get the `t`

In your code, you concatenate the index -1 and the index +1 leading to `et`

You should omit the + 1 in `str[str.length/2 + 1]` like:

```
function getMiddle(str) {
    return str.length % 2 === 0 ? str[str.length / 2 - 1] + str[str.length / 2] : str[Math.floor(str.length / 2)];
}
```

```js
function getMiddle(str) {
  return str.length % 2 === 0 ? str[str.length / 2 - 1] + str[str.length / 2] : str[Math.floor(str.length / 2)];
}

console.log(getMiddle("testing"));
console.log(getMiddle("test"));
console.log(getMiddle("testtest"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand a use of ternary is required but you may simply do this without any such conditionals as well.

```js
var getmid = (s, i=s.length/2) => s.slice(Math.ceil(i-1), Math.ceil(i+1)-(s.length & 1));
console.log(getmid("test"));  // <- "es"
console.log(getmid("testo")); // <- "s"
```